# HTML: checkbox using c# razor & model

Tags: c#, html

i have a checkbox that i'm using the model's company value to see if it should be checked.
company value can have more than one company as such: 1,9,10,15

in this case of multiple companies, following statement will never be true.

```
<input type=checkbox id=drsc class="comp" value="9" data-mini="true"   @(Model.company=="9" ? "data-chkd=true" : "") />
```

so i'm trying to use logic below using the 'contains' clause and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<input type=checkbox id=nn class="comp" value="9" data-mini="true"  @((Model.company).Contains("9") ? "data-chkd=true" : "") />
```

if my company field has just company 9, first stmt is working.  but not 2nd.
any thoughts?

Comment: You should really show your code.

Comment: @Ek0nomik found it: he put it up, but not formatted correctly, so it was invisible

Comment: What type is `Model.company`? It looks like a string, but consider the fact that `"10".Contains("1")` is true. That looks like it should be an `IList<int>`.

Comment: Is the company property just a comma delimited string?  Should it be a list instead?  update: heh, posted at same time as Tim.

Comment: post the string that is `Model.company`

Answer (score 3):

**UPD:**

Try use razor syntax:

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkBoxName", Model.company == "9", new { id = "drsc", @class = "comp", value = "9", data_mini = "true" })
```

Result html code will be:

```
<input class="comp" data-mini="true" id="drsc" name="checkBoxName" type="checkbox" value="9">
```

if you have array of companies like this:

```
public class TmpModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> companies = new int[] { 1, 9, 10, 15 };
}
```

this code make checkbox checked if company **9** is one of **model.companies**

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkBoxName", Model.companies.Contains(9), new { id = "drsc", @class = "comp", value = "9", data_mini = "true" })
```